# Are there alternative to using intellipoint?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

Are there alternative to using intellipoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small project called [**MouseHook**](http://mousehook.de/) which aims to be an IntelliPoint replacement. It is still under development though so it's not quite perfect, but usable in it's current state nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) for mouse button redefining.
I forgot what else the Intellipoint gives me, but its probably nothing of value. :-)

Here is a quick script to redefine some mouse buttons. See the [Mouse](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) and [Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) documentation for complete details.

```
;; This is an AutoHotKey script. This line is a comment

;; Forces the unconditional installation of the mouse hook.

#InstallMouseHook

;; By default, override key input for all applications.
;;
;; XButton1 and 2 should correspond to the shoulder buttons.
;; XButton1 will input Enter key

XButton1:: SendInput {Enter}

;; XButton2 will input Backspace key

XButton2:: SendInput {Backspace}

;; Also can set per application.
;;
;; For Windows Command console windows (cmd.exe)
;; (they can be referenced programmatically using
;; "ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass"),
;;  XButton1 will input the textual contents of
;;  the current clipboard.

#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
  XButton1::SendInput {raw}%Clipboard%
#IfWinActive

;; The previous line is necessary to reset Hotkey definitions
;; back to all applications.
```

The above was tested on a Windows XP "Computer Administrator" account. :-p I believe it should work in Windows 7 as well.
Also, tested with a device with the "HID-compliant mouse" driver.

(BTW, this should be better than MouseHook because the latter does not seem to be open source or documented. I tried out MouseHook, but configuration is very difficult if you don't know what scan codes you want to use and if you don't know the syntax of the XML file. I was able to duplicate the above settings though, so it seems functional.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what features of Intellipoint you need. I use button mapping and http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm is just great for it! It even works in the UAC'ed process, when Intellipoint does not!